# Slurm - randomize GPU allocation

Tags: slurm

We are setting up Slurm on a single computer-server equipped with 4 GPUs. I have been trying to find a way to have Slurm allocate a job to a random GPU, where I use "random" in a relaxed way, meaning for instance that if GPU 1 is being used, then a new job requesting GPU resources should be allocated on a random GPU anomg those that are free (0, 2, 3)

The problem is that, as it is now, Slurm always allocates GPU0 first, then GPU1, then 2, 3. This causes GPU0 to execute considerably more jobs over time, and therefore wear down faster. A randomized selection would be better.

I have read the documentation regarding Sbatch etc, but it seems that one can select a specific GPU to run a job, but not pick it randomly as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and wrote a program doing this. Please see https://github.com/gqqnbig/randomize-gpu

Mainly, you run the following script before starting slurmd.

```sh
#! /usr/bin/zsh -e

setopt extended_glob
# --force bypasses the error
# "rm: missing operand", when there are no files to delete.
rm --force /dev/rNvidia[0-9]#(N)
nvidias=( $(printf '%s\n' /dev/nvidia[0-9]# | shuf) )
for ((i = 1; i <= $#nvidias; i++)) do
    echo "Link "${nvidias[$i]}" to rNvidia$((i-1))"
    ln -s ${nvidias[$i]} /dev/rNvidia$((i-1))
done
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet (planning to). Does it enable this GPU index randomization before every job, or only when `slurmd` starts? i.e. after you've started `slurmd`, all jobs will pick a GPU not in the 0,1,2,3 order, but still in a deterministic order? (say 2,0,3,1).

Comment: @Guillaume It shuffles GPU order when `slurmd` starts.  all jobs still pick GPUs in a deterministic order. It's just barely usable.

Comment: This is good enough on a workstation that gets rebooted regularly. But I can't get this to work, even (seemingly) properly set up, my slurm jobs always grab GPU 0 first. I will bring this up on your repo's issues on GitHub when I find time to write it up, this will be more convenient than here.